# python auto-complete: for example: sp['close'].plot.his [TAB] - should this work? (expand to "hist")

Tags: pandas, autocomplete

python auto-complete: for example: sp['close'].plot.his [TAB] // to expect his to expand in hist (or any other options starting w/ "his" ) 
is there a reason why this won't work?

Comment: That isn't python... its your ide.  What are you using to edit your code?

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupyter notebook.

This should work because Jupyter can see that `pd.Series.plot` has a `hist` method.

```
pd.Series.plot.his[TAB] # should autocomplete
```

[image]

This doesn't work... yet.  Because Jupyter cannot see past the brackets in  `['close']` to determine what the return value will be and subsequently what the attributes and methods are.

```
sp['close'].plot.his [TAB]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to fetch a value from a Python object using tab-completion, Python itself doesn't provide this feature. Instead, the behavior of tab-completion typically depends on the Integrated Development Environment (IDE) or interactive environment you're using. Some Python language servers integrated into certain IDEs can offer auto-completion for object methods and their parameters, but this functionality varies depending on your chosen IDE and its configuration.

If you jupyter nootbook inside VScode using jupyter extensions, I think it will work as you expect.

[image]